# Can I target a specific form for commenting with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created a news system on my web page where I use while loop to echo my news on a page. With news I created a form for news where I target it by name and I want to use jquery to process the results. When I use php it works fine but I want to avoid reloading page with submitting form and immediate post comment to page.

my form looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comments" id="comments">
    <textarea id="comment_area" class="comment-area" name="comment" placeholder="Dodajte svoj komentar tukaj..."></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="news_id" name="news_id" value="' . $row['news_id'] . '">
    <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="comment_btn" class="comment-btn" name="comments<php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" value="Objavi">
</form>'
```

my php code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['comments' . $row['news_id'] . '']) === true && empty($_POST['comment']) === false) {

global $user_data; 

$user_id    = $user_data['user_id'];
$connect_id = $_POST['news_id'];
$type       = $_POST['type'];
$time       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$comment    = $_POST['comment'];
$comment    = sanitize($comment);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`user_id`, `connect_id`, `type`, `time`, `comment`) VALUES ('$user_id', '$connect_id', '$type', '$time', '$comment')");
}
```

If I try to do somethink like this:

```
$(".comment-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = $('.comment-area').val();

    console.log(text);

    $('.comment-area').val('');
});
```

It targets only the form where is the first news and doesn't target all the forms.

Is there any way to do this differently???

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
$(".comment-btn").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentArea = $(this).siblings(".comment-area");
        var text = commentArea.val();
        console.log(text);
        commentArea.val('');
    });
});
```

The problem is that while this `$(".comment-btn")` returns an array of all the button in the forms you mentioned, this `$(".comment-btn").click(...` attaches a click event handler only for the first item of the array.

```js
$(function(){ 
    $(".comment-btn").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var commentArea = $(this).siblings(".comment-area");
            var text = commentArea.val();
            console.log(text);
            commentArea.val('');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comments" id="comments">
    <textarea id="comment_area" class="comment-area" name="comment" placeholder="Dodajte svoj komentar tukaj..."></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="news_id" name="news_id" value="' . $row['news_id'] . '">
    <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="comment_btn" class="comment-btn" name="comments<php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" value="Objavi">
</form>'

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comments" id="comments">
    <textarea id="comment_area" class="comment-area" name="comment" placeholder="Dodajte svoj komentar tukaj..."></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="news_id" name="news_id" value="' . $row['news_id'] . '">
    <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="comment_btn" class="comment-btn" name="comments<php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" value="Objavi">
</form>'

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comments" id="comments">
    <textarea id="comment_area" class="comment-area" name="comment" placeholder="Dodajte svoj komentar tukaj..."></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="news_id" name="news_id" value="' . $row['news_id'] . '">
    <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="comment_btn" class="comment-btn" name="comments<php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" value="Objavi">
</form>'
```

Comment: I tryed to do this but it returnes me the error of undefined.

Comment: Did you try the snippet and it returned undefined? I supposte that the HTML you have is like the one in the snippet. Multiple forms each of them includin news.

Comment: Yes is exactly like snippet. I tryed it and it returned endefined

Comment: @MladenRailić The intention of the snippet is to log the content entered in a textarea and then clear this textarea, when the button of the form is clicked. If a textarea is empty and the corresponding button being clicked, then output would be undefined. We can capture this and we can avoid to log it. Do you want this?

Comment: Now I understood what you ment. Sorry for taking me so long but my englesh is not so good that I thougt. Your answer did the trick. Thank you a lot...it buged me for very long time.

Comment: @MladenRailić You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery `on` function to bind "click" event to all buttons with `comment-btn` class. However, it'll be important to then identify which `comment-area` you want to refer to. If that is not done, it'll simply erase the values of all fields / textareas with class `comment-area`.

```
$(".comment-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var text = $(this).parent().find('.comment-area').val();
    console.log(text);
    $(this).parent().find('.comment-area').val('');
});
```

Working example with the only change being that input type for buttons is changed from "submit" to "button":
https://jsfiddle.net/L87n4Ljo/

Likewise, if you'd like to submit a particular form when the button is clicked, you'll have to do so by specifically identifying that form by using `parent()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here we are blocking the default form submit which i think you will need if you don't want to reload the page.

```js
$(".comments").on("submit", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $(this).find('.comment-area').val();
        console.log(text);
        $(this).find('.comment-area').val('');

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="comments" id="comments">
    <textarea id="comment_area" class="comment-area" name="comment" placeholder="Dodajte svoj komentar tukaj..."></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="news_id" name="news_id" value="' . $row['news_id'] . '">
    <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="comment_btn" class="comment-btn" name="comments<php echo $row['news_id'] ?>" value="Objavi">
</form>'
```